# I still cant get a runnable jar file out of this source code

Tags: java, jar, executable

I have tried many time to add the correct libraries, make sure I have the right manifest, and even reset the project properties. The strangest thing about the jar file I render is that it runs just fine on my computer but will not on others. the source code is open and available here to anyone who is interested. https://github.com/nicklanetv/itdops/tree/master

Comment: Class names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: Looks like a classpath problem. Have you checked all libraries are in place?

Comment: What errors/issues do you see when it fails to run?

Comment: Main class is unable to be found @MadConan

Comment: Unless you tell us (**precisely**) how you are trying to compile / build the JAR, what the manifest looks like, and what errors you are seeing we can't really help you.  There's nothing about the Java source code in your repo that should cause any problems.

Comment: I had this exact issue the other day, The issue was the other computers were using a different JRE (I had 7, they had 6).  Have you checked to see that the relevan't JRE's match up?

Comment: Is there any way to make it available across all platforms maybe a jpln file? @user2777005

Comment: That would certainly be a way to go, although I have no idea how. The other option would be to to compile it for a lower version of JVM, which would widen the range of JRE it is compatible with.

Comment: @user  I compiled with Javac in cmd and it seemed to fix it